# React-Native Firebase real-time db flatlist example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to list the json data I got from Firebase with flatlist.

My JSONL

[image]

My code:

```
database()
.ref('/DOHOL')
.on('value', snapshot => {
  //console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
  const datas = snapshot.val();
  for (const [key, deger] of Object.entries(datas)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${deger}`);
   
    for (const [key, degerr] of Object.entries(deger)) {
      
      console.log(`${key}: ${degerr}`);
      
      
    }
  }
}
);

 <FlatList
      data={deger}
      renderItem={({ item }) => 
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
        
      }
    />
```

Error:

[image]

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `deger` (and many others) is a local const in the callback where you define it. Since the flatlist is rendered from elsewhere, it can't access local variables of that callback.

To share data between code and rendering, you'll need to store it in the state of the object. For example with:

```
for (const [key, deger] of Object.entries(datas)) {
  setState({ deger });
  ...
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setState

Comment: Did you try to solve that part of the problem yourself already? https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%27t+find+variable%3A+setState has some good leads.